# How get full objets with a pointer?

Tags: pointers, cloud, parse-server

How get full objets with pointers?.
I have this

```
ParseObject { _objCount: 4, className: 'Task', id: 'I593WXO24i' }
```

Update:

This is my code

```
             var taskQuery = new Parse.Query("Task");

             taskQuery.get(req.params.task,{
                 success: function(task){

                     console.log(task);
                 },
                 error: function(error){
                     errorCodeFor(res, "not_found", "item.task", "Task was not found");
                 }
             });
```

But when console.log(task).I have a pointers.I want the full object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the include method:
https://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/#relational-queries

It would be something like this:

```
query.include('myPointerFieldName');
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include also the console.log call? If you call console.log(task) inside the "success" function block, you should have the object.

Comment: Not.I do not!.I have not de full object :(

Comment: Can you please try "console.log(task.get('someOfYourFields'))"?

Comment: I get someOfYourFields,
but I have to insert task in an array of tasks objects, and task is a pointer

Comment: If you are getting someOfYourFields, it is not a Pointer. It is an object.

Comment: When I insert is the pointer, but , very thanks for you time Davi